# Set container object

Tags: c++, string, stl, set

```
class CallerId{
private:
    string name;
    int* number;
public:
       .
       .
}
```

I have this class and I wish to put objects of that type in a set container with ascending and descending order (based on the string name).
Is there any possible way to do so?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: write an `operator<()` then use `std::set`

Comment: Yes, please be more specific about what have you tried. This is straight forward (use std::set) and implement the < operator

Comment: I am trying:
CallerId a("George", 123);
CallerId b("Jenny", 582);
set<CallerId> f;
f.insert(a);
f.insert(b);

but it gives me an error regarding stl library.

Comment: @Penny - It would be much more interesting if you told us WHAT error you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like to use `std::set` you have to implement `operator <` ...

```
#include <set>

class CallerId{
private:
    std::string name;
    int* number;
public:
    CallerId( std::string na, int* nu=nullptr) : name(na), number(nu) {}
    bool operator <( const CallerId &src) const { return name < src.name; }
};

std::set<CallerId> callIdSet;
callIdSet.insert( CallerId( "a" ) );
callIdSet.insert( CallerId( "b" ) );
```

... an other way is to use `std::map` where `CallerId::name` is your key ...

```
#include <map>

class CallerId{
private:
    std::string name;
    int* number;
public:
    CallerId( std::string na, int* nu=nullptr) : name(na), number(nu) {}
    const std::string& Name() const { return name; }
};

CallerId ida("a");
CallerId idb("b");
std::map<std::string,CallerId> callIdMap;
callIdMap.emplace( ida.Name(), ida );
callIdMap.emplace( idb.Name(), idb );
```

Answer (score -1):

Sure, create a `std::list<CallerId>` and sort it using [sort member function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/).

You define yourself a function to compare two objects of that class and pass it to `sort`.

Comment: I have to do it using Set.